# How to get enemy's armor in Fallout Tactics?

Tags: fallout-tactics

How to get [Vandal armor](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Vandal_armor) in Fallout Tactics? Do I need some skill to loot enemy's armor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you can't get the Vandal Armor in the Game. Well there is sometimes the possibility to loot that armor (perhabs a Bug?) from a Raider's Corpse. But its a very low chance you be able to.